# Getting Rating for an App from Apple AppStore

Tags: ios, bash, app-store, rating, rate

I want to create a report regarding my App's rating in three dimensions - date, Country and App Version (I know that from Android I can get in a query only Date+Another Dim, not quite sure how it works with Apple...). I found the "Reporter" (https://help.apple.com/itc/appsreporterguide/#/itcbd9ed14ac) but it allows me only finance reports... I also saw the RSS option - only this option gives me the "last X reviews"' and I just want an aggregated data (lets say - for each day, how many 1 star rating, 2 star rating etc'...)

If someone can help me with how to do so (preferably in bash/python script), I'd really appriciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to get them out of iTunes Connect is probably with Spaceship. (App > Activity > Ratings & Reviews

`# Get reviews for a given store front
reviews = ratings.reviews("US") # => Array of hashes representing review data`

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/spaceship/docs/iTunesConnect.md#app-ratings--reviews

Comment: This questions asks specifically for ratings but this answer is for reviews.

Comment: You can do the same for ratings. Feel free to edit my more than 2 year old answer instead of just negatively commenting.

Answer (score -1):

The Appfigures API can give you ratings and reviews for iOS and Android apps.

The following request will give you the last 50 reviews from any country, but you can easily get more reviews, limit by country/version/etc.

`GET https://api.appfigures.com/v2/reviews?count=50`

While will give you something like this:

```
{
    "total": 140,
    "pages": 28,
    "this_page": 1,
    "reviews": [{
        "author": "DeveloperToDeveloper",
        "title": "Just Spectacular",
        "review": "Finally able to remove the ads! The description is hilarious!! Thanks!!!",
        "original_title": null,
        "original_review": null,
        "stars": "5.00",
        "iso": "US",
        "version": "1.2",
        "date": "2017-05-19T17:05:00",
        "product": 6567539,
        "weight": 0,
        "id": "5561747L7xnbsMRu8UbPvy7A71Dv6A=="
    }]
}
```

Here's how you'd do it with Python:

```
import requests

USERNAME = 'USERNAME'
PASSWORD = 'PASSWORD'
APP_KEY = 'APP_KEY'
BASE_URI = "https://api.appfigures.com/v2/"

# Helper function for auth and app_key
# first / in uri is optional
def make_request(uri, **querystring_params):
  headers = {"X-Client-Key": APP_KEY}
  auth =(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
  return requests.get(BASE_URI + uri.lstrip("/"),
                        auth=auth,
                        params=querystring_params,
                        headers=headers)

# Get the last 50 reviews for all of our apps
reviews_response = make_request("/reviews", 
                                count=50)
assert 200 == reviews_response.status_code
assert 0 < len(reviews_response.json())

# Use the response to sum up ratings, analyze review text, etc.
```

FYI - Reviews and ratings are separate for apps, and while the 5 star rating on a review *contributes* to the total rating, there could also be ratings that aren't associated with a written review.

Those can be retrieved using the [Ratings](https://docs.appfigures.com/api/reference/v2/reports-ratings) route.